# Why when i am sending blob in fetch i can download file but when i am using axios it will not work?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

So in fetch i am using this

```
 const response = await fetch(
    `download`,
  )
    .then((response) => response.blob())
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);

      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(res);
      downloadLink.download = "test.zip";

      // Programmatically trigger the download
      downloadLink.click();
 });
```

At this it works perfectly  but when i use this code for axios  the file not open

````
await axios
    .get("download", {
      responseType: "blob",
    })
    .then(async (response) => {
      const blob = new Blob([response.data]);

      const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      downloadLink.download = "test.zip";
      // Programmatically trigger the download
      downloadLink.click();
    });
  //   });```
````

I have tried to use another more options but it didnt work

Comment: It looks it went wrong with a blob. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72229972/3731501

Answer (score -1):

The code you provided for handling the download using Axios looks correct. However, there might be an issue with the way you are handling the response or triggering the download. Here's a modified version of your code that should work:

```
 await axios
 .get("download", {
            responseType: "blob",
        })
 .then((response) => {
            const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
            const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));

            downloadLink.href = URL;
            downloadLink.setAttribute("download", "test.zip");

            // Programmatically trigger the download
            downloadLink.click();

            // Clean up the URL object after the download
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        });
```

In this code, we create a URL object using `URL.createObjectURL` and assign it to the `href` property of the download link. We also set the download attribute to specify the filename. Finally, we trigger the download by programmatically clicking the download link.

Make sure you are using this code in an environment that supports the Blob and URL APIs, such as a web browser.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/11107541