# FastAPI's StreamingResponse doesn't return stream

Tags: http, fastapi, streamingresponsebody

Trying FastAPI's `StreamingResponse`, however getting `TypeError: stream.on is not a function` in the browser:

```
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/stream", {
      responseType: "stream",
    });

    const stream = response.data;

    stream.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log(event.data);
    });
```

Server endpoint (code snippet):

```
    def get_stream():
        yield 'a'
        yield 'b'
        yield 'c'


    @app.get("/stream")
    async def main():
        return StreamingResponse(get_stream(), media_type="text/plain")
```

I also tried passing `--h11-max-incomplete-event-size 0` argument to uvicorn command as mentioned here: https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60048180/is-it-possible-to-post-a-responsetype-stream-in-axios ? It doesn't seem like `stream` is valid in a browser context in axios. In any case, the response type wouldn't differ from a regular response, just that FastAPI would hand over data piecemeal.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI StreamingResponse not streaming with generator function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75740652/fastapi-streamingresponse-not-streaming-with-generator-function)

Comment: @Chris no because I'm streaming specifically to the browser. As @MatsLindh pointed out it's an issue with axios, I got it working using `fetch`